# Convert separator character while escaping separator in fields

Tags: csv, text-formatting

I have a text file with fields delimited by `|`. I want to convert it to `,` like a typical CSV. I have tried to use this:

```
sed 's/|/,/g' test.txt > test.csv
```

but some of the fields already have commas in them. For example:

```
var1|var2|var3
Potter, Harry|2|3
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
sed 's/|/","/g; s/^/"/; s/$/"/' file
```

This will produce output like this:

```
"var1","var2","var3"
"Potter, Harry","2","3"
```

**Explanation:**

You need to enclose each of your column using quotes `""` .

- First `s/|/","/g` replaces all `|` with `","` comma enclosed in quotes 
  Output : 
  `var1","var2","var3
  Potter, Harry","2","3`
- Second `s/^/"/` replaces the beginning of line with quotes where `^` means beginning of line
- Third `s/$/"/` replaces the end of line with quotes where `$` means end of line

You can also escape the commas in field using backslash before each comma something like this

```
Potter\, Harry,2,3
```

You can read more about csv formatting here: https://www.csvreader.com/csv_format.php

Comment: Yes. It works. Thanks. Can you please explain it a bit. I didn't get the part after the first column.

Comment: I have edited the answer , let me know if any more explanation is needed

Answer (score 5):

Use the right csv parser tool:

```
csvtool -t '|' -u ',' cat infile > outputfile
var1,var2,var3
"Potter, Harry",2,3
```

---

#### from `csvtool --help`:

```
-t   Input separator char.  Use -t TAB for tab separated input.
-u   Output separator char.  Use -u TAB for tab separated output.
cat
    This concatenates the input files together and writes them to
    the output.  You can use this to change the separator character.
```

Answer (score 3):

To quote only the values that contain commas:

```
$ sed 's/[^|]*,[^|]*/"&"/; y/|/,/' <infile
var1,var2,var3
"Potter, Harry",2,3
```

If the input already contained double quote characters, and they were not being used for CSV formatting (like for `Riddle, Tom "Voldemort"|4|5`), then for most csv formats, you escape them with `""`:

```
$ sed 's/"/""/g; s/[^|]*[,"][^|]*/"&"/; y/|/,/' <infile
"Riddle, Tom ""Voldemort""",4,5
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to read the input as pipe-delimited CSV and writing the output as comma-delimited CSV:

```bash
$ mlr --csv --ifs pipe cat file
var1,var2,var3
"Potter, Harry",2,3
```

The same thing using `csvformat` from [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/):

```bash
$ csvformat -d '|' file
var1,var2,var3
"Potter, Harry",2,3
```

Answer (score -1):

You can modify your regex to include \w, witch matches any alphanumeric and _ followed by a |

```
 #sed 's/\w|/,/g' example.csv 
 var1|var2|var3
 Potter, Harry|2|3
```

Comment: It doesn't work. I got output like this: Porter, Harr, ,3