# convert tab delimited data to , delimited records with double quoted fields " "

Tags: text-processing, sed, csv

I want to convert tab delimited csv into " ", add empty space if value is empty

```
FirstName      LastName        Address1             Address2              City          State  ZIP         
John1           Mark            149 Lower Stereet                          California     CA      05478
John2           Mark                                149 Lower, Stereet    California     CA      05478
John3           Mark            149 ,Lower Stereet                         California     CA      05478
```

with the desired result

```
"FirstName","LastName","Address1","Address2","City","State","ZIP"        
"John1","Mark","149 Lower Stereet", ,"California","CA","05478"
"John2","Mark", ,"149 Lower, Stereet","California","CA","05478"
"John3","Mark","149,Lower Stereet", , "California","CA","05478"
```

I tried with below command

```
sed 's/\t\+/,/g;s/^\|$/"/g;s/,/"&"/g' Actual.csv > Actual_V6.csv
```

Output

```
"FirstName","LastName","Address1","Address2","City","State","ZIP
"
"John1","Mark1","149 Lower Stereet","California","CA","05489
"
"John2","Mark","149 Lower"," Stereet","California","CA","05489","
"
"John3","Mark","149 ","Lower Stereet","California","CA","05489"
```

Where

1. "149 ,Lower Stereet" convert into "149 Lower"," Stereet"  it's
   supposed to be "149 Lower, Stereet"
2. adding " in the next line
3. Empty values are not recognized

**EDIT**

Output of `hexdump`:

[image: Hexa]

[image: Source]

[image: Result]

Comment: Do you have two tabs (converted to spaces?) in the line with "John2"? And why is the field "City" repeated?

Comment: Hi Strobbe, I have update city to State it's my bad

Comment: I don't have two tabs in the line with "John2"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert separator character while escaping separator in fields](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/445232/convert-separator-character-while-escaping-separator-in-fields)

Comment: Misleading title. You want to convert to `,` delimited records with double quoted fields.

Comment: Just convert the tab directly to ‘“,”’

Comment: It looks like I cannot reproduce your `"` on the next line. There may be some character at the end of your lines that is not copied here (in the source of your question). You may want to post the "raw" value of some of your lines; for instance, the output of `head -2 file | hexdump -C`.

Comment: Could you see the image result

Comment: @Sanj Why do you want to use csv for data with ‘,’ in the value? That is just wrong

Comment: even thought it's txt format i am getting " in the next line ... I need this. Is there any way i can move " to upper line . Are you able to replicate this ?

Comment: Not sure this is _the_ cause for your `"` on the next line, but your file seems to use Windows `CR-LF` end of line sequences (you can spot them as `0d 0a`). If it is what you want, you can get rid of them by adding a `s/\r//g;` (or `'s/\o015//g'`) to your `sed` command, as in `sed 's/\r//g; s/\t/","/g; s/.*/"&"/; s/""/ /g'`.

Comment: @fra-san  .... Thank you very much It's working sed 's/\r//g; s/\t/","/g; s/.*/"&"/; s/""/ /g'

Comment: @Sanj, note that for CSV, any fields that contain double quotes, the quotes must be doubled. Try this: `sed -E 's/\r$//; s/"/""/g; s/\t/","/g; s/^/"/; s/$/"/' file.tsv`

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
sed 's/\t/","/g; s/.*/"&"/; s/""/ /g' file
```

`s/""/ /g` is not really necessary to have a proper csv but to achieve your desired output.

If you have `csvtool`:

```
csvtool -t TAB -u ',' cat file
```

This will only quote the fields where necessary.

Comment: Hi Rovo,I tried with above it's working fine except adding " to the next line

Comment: "FirstName","LastName","Address1","Address2","City","State","ZIP
"
"John1","Mark1","149 Lower Stereet", ,"California","CA","05489
"
"John2","Mark", ,"149 Lower, Stereet","California","CA","05489
"
"John3","Mark","149 ,Lower Stereet", ,"California","CA","05489"

Comment: "FirstName","LastName","Address1","Address2","City","State","ZIP

Comment: " added to next line

Comment: "John1","Mark1","149 Lower Stereet","California","CA","05489

Comment: Could you see the image result

Answer (score 0):

Not near a comp so can’t test but how about a simple

```
Sed -r ‘s/^/“/;s/$/“/;s/\t/“,”/g;s/“”/ /g’
```

?
I think the question is wrong though. Quotation marks inside the original tsv will likely confuse any parser requiring them in the final result

Comment: That works, even though the empty fields get converted into `""` instead of just a space between the commas. (See the desired result in the question.)

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe added last conversion, hope that’s better, still can’t test

Comment: The new version(s) convert empty fields into quoted single spaces. (In the first version, empty fields were converted into empty quotes, i.e. without a space between them.) B.t.w.: typo: simle -> simple.

Comment: Why it's getting " in the next line for each row

Comment: @Sanj still can’t test but most probably because input has empty lines (or more specifically lines with ^[[:space:]]*\n$ )

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe thanks for spotting the typo